Convert MBF Band pass to differential band-pass
The problem
I need to design a differential to single-end band-pass filter & amplifier before an ADC (sampling at 8kHz) :

DC-blocking
0dB at 60Hz
10dB (ideally 20dB) for frequency above 120Hz
-20dB at 4kHz (anti-aliasing)
Band pass-ripple isn't a problem

Proposed solution
My solution is using Analog Filter Wizard I found this solution that look promising


I want to convert it to differential and here is my take. However I can't find a way to simulate it on lt-spice, is it correct?
Questions
How should I wire the negative feedback and positive feedback to convert it to fully differential? Two voltage divider on going from negative output to positive input and vice-versa? This is my take on the conversion :



I need to design a differential to single-end band-pass filter &
amplifier

If you want my opinion I'd just use the single ended filter circuit you have and put a differential amplifier in front of it like this: -

The advantages far outweigh the added cost of an extra stage and the inflexibility of making differential filters. There's also the availability of better parts (single ended op-amps) and many, many more to choose from. It's a no-brainer to me.

I thought about filtering before amplifying and converting first stage from differential to single ended. However I've read that keeping the differential signal reduce noise at the ADC stage.
If I amplify first, I fear that the 50Hz will saturate my signal (it's for a magnetometer so 50Hz/60Hz is always strong). What is the benefit of amplifying first?

Differential does reduce noise but only if your ADC is used differentially (and you say not in your question). BTW please don't retrospectively change your question should this be an error on your part because I have provided an answer. You can make a low-noise differential front-end amplifier/attenuator that handles big common-mode voltages quite easily. If you find that you need more common-mode rejection capability, you change two resistors and, this leaves your filter stages unaffected. It's more complex to change the differential filter to handle higher common-mode signals @Skipper
